# Is it possible to use a mathematical expression as function name?

Tags: function-construction, syntax

This might seem as a silly question, but is it feasible to use a mathematical expression as the name of a function?

For example, I'm studying the cross section of Compton scattering and there is a formula for the differential cross section, which is denoted as $\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}$. I'd like to express the latter as a function of energy E, angle θ and atomic number Z.

If I, naively, use $\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}[Z\_, E\_, \theta\_] := \ldots$ I get the anticipated error:

> SetDelayed::write : Tag Times in dσ/dΩ[Z_,E_,θ_] is Protected

Instead of the obvious workaround of using a name such as `diffSection`[Z_,E_,θ_] := ... is there any other way ?

Comment: A big barred underscript could do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the Notation package:

```
<< Notation`
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[FractionBox["dσ", "dΩ"]]]
(dσ/dΩ)[Ε_, r_, θ_] := f[Ε, r, θ]
```

[image: Notation package used to make a complicated symbol]

Comment: Worked perfect! Thanks @TimothyWofford!